# The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-gradle-3.0

After upgrading to Gradle 4.x, I [get the warning](https://travis-ci.org/DialogsForAndroid/dialogs-for-android/builds/307430731)

> The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.

in one of my projects. I don't see anything called `bootClasspath` or similar in my [build.gradle](https://github.com/DialogsForAndroid/dialogs-for-android/blob/572f020/commons/build.gradle). What does this warning mean?

the warning only appears in the **commons** subproject, not in **core**.

commons/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'commons'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '0.9.2.3'
    BUILD_TOOLS = "26.0.3"
    TARGET_SDK = 25
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
        versionCode 1
        versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
}

// Changes to this block must be applied in core/build.gradle and commons/build.gradle
task("javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    description "Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code."
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
    exclude "**/BuildConfig.java"
    exclude "**/R.java"
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
}
```

core/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'core'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '0.9.2.3'
    SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.4.0'
    BUILD_TOOLS = "26.0.3"
    TARGET_SDK = 25
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
    buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK
        versionCode 1
        versionName PUBLISH_VERSION
        consumerProguardFiles 'progress-proguard.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    api "com.android.support:support-v13:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    api "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    implementation "me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.1"
}

// Changes to this block must be applied in core/build.gradle and commons/build.gradle
task("javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    description "Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code."
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
    exclude "**/BuildConfig.java"
    exclude "**/R.java"
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My Gradle is using OpenJDK 8 from `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre` on Ubuntu (see by adding `println System.getProperty("java.home")` in build.gradle. No Android Studio involved.

I can trigger the the warning by explicitly setting `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to 1.7 (the default value). By changing the Java version to

```
android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

the warning disappears.

The reason why the warning is shown for only one project is that it is not repeated. `commons` is configured before `core` because of [alphanumerical ordering](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:configuration_time_dependencies). When I set `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to 1.8 for `commons`, the warning moves to `core`.

Setting `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to 1.8 for all projects removes the warning entirely. If this is what you want for your project and why Gradle 4 cannot be used warning-free with 1.7 are two separate questions.

Comment: Could not find method compileOptions()

Answer (score 16):

I think this message about java Classpath and old JDK, adding this to your gradle will solve it:

```
android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

It's recommended to use java 9 JDK and uninstall old one then include it to your project structure: `File` -> `Other settings` -> `Default project structure`.

[image]

**Possible conclusion:**

Default JDK for android-studio is `...\Android studio\jre` (The embedded JDK) as shown in above image. This embedded JDK contain the deprecated **bootClasspath**.

Using the new JDK which contain **bootstrapClasspath**  or modify your `compileOptions` will solve it.

**Why the old JDK (Embedded one) not compatible with new *gradle version*?**

I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I wrote a more detailed answer based on your suggestions which leaves out any JDK 9 solution, which is not suitable in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

The foregoing aside, I can offer-up where the error arises for a `Java` build.  The referenced: `CompileOptions.bootClasspath` must point to a Java run-time JAR matching the intended target system. That means, for example, if you are compiling to run your program on a server using Java 6, you need to set the `bootClasspath` to point at a *compatible* Java6 runtime, viz.: **`rt.jar`**

I normally set-up a project variable / environment variable to point to this file:

- `BOOT_CLASSPATH`

It normally lives with the JRE, not in the JDK except under the `jre` folder.

In the project Gradle script, we have:

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava, ]*.options*.bootClasspath = BOOT_CLASSPATH
```

Set explicitly.  However in some other scripts, we don't set the `bootClasspath` overtly at all, and still have the message in question.

```
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated
and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the    
CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
```

... *anyway*.  I thusly surmise that the Java plugin is doing that itself as some default behaviour.  I realise that's only background story.  I may assist resolving the warning.

CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath`